# Jquery with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have been building a rails 4 app and I need some simple jquery functions. Specifically, I need to run some javascript after a nested_form javascript call (which works fine, but of course was provided). I have scoured the internet and nothing that I find is working even in the slightest (like an alert window once a page is finished loading). Can someone please show me exactly what to do for just a simple alert window on a specific page? The nested_form github shows me how to do the rest. Thank you.

My code:

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= fullTitle(yield(:title))%></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
...
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery_nested_form


$(document).onDomReady(function()
{
    alert("works1!")
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("works2!")
});

$(document).on('page:load', ready)(function()
{
    alert("works3!")
});

$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
    alert("works4!");
    var field = event.field;
    $field.each('input[id=name]').val("testing!");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of turbolinks in Rails 4, you'll have to bind on both `$(document).ready` and `$(document).on( 'page:load')`. Try changing your code to

```
var ready = function() {
  alert( 'works!' );
  // or any other code to execute
};

$(document).ready( ready );
$(document).on( 'page:load', ready );
```

Comment: That works, but only when I reload a page. Is that the intended functionality?

Comment: @Megawolf The `ready` function will be executed when the page is reloaded (or invoked directly via the url) or when it is loaded via turbolinks (the default in Rails 4). E.g. Let's say you have the following routes: `/contacts` and `/contacts/1`. If you load `http://localhost:3000/contacts` in the browser, the ready function will fire because of `$(document).ready`. In that view, if you have a `link_to 'foo', '/contacts/1'` and you click on it, Rails will load the page via turbolinks (by default) and the ready function will fire because of `$(document).on('page:load')`

Answer (score 1):

I like to add an additional gem to ensure that jQuery functions appropriately. [JQuery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) fixes the binding events that turbolinks messes with.

Gemfile should then include the following

```
# Gemfile
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'

# application.js
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```